# Attachment placement in a RTF Mail

Tags: c#, outlook, rtf

I want to send a `Mail` via `Outlook` and `C#` but I have a problem with the placement of my `Attachments`. I have the following code:

```
if (strBody.StartsWith(@"{\rtf"))
{   
    mailItem.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatRichText;                    
    mailItem.RTFBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strBody);

    mailItem.Attachments.Add(strAttachment, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, int.MaxValue, null);

}
else
{
    mailItem.Body = strBody;
    mailItem.Attachments.Add(strAttachment, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, null);
}
```

My strBody has the following Value:

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue128;\red0\green128\blue255;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\fs20 Sehr geehrte \cf1 Damen\cf0  und \cf2 Herren\cf0 ,\par
\par
hier ihre AB\fs20\par
}

But my `Mail` looks like this:

[image: RTF Mail Body]

Now my Question is,

1. Can the `Attachments` be displayed as an extra Row like when the Mail is not RTF formatted?
2. If not 1., then how can I get my `Attachments` to be displayed at the End?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you did everything right. Every value > 1 will place the attachment at the end of your mail. After "hier ihre AB" it is placed. Looks stupid but well... 
As a little workaround, I used it like that too, place some new lines. As much as it takes to place the Attachment under your last sentence.

Or you write the Mail as a HTML Type. Less problems.

EDIT:

[image]

As you can see, the file is placed at the end of the mail.

EDIT II:

Here is a example for a method to send your E-Mail as HTML with the attachment in the attachment row:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            Outlook.Application tmpOutlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem tmpMessage = (Outlook.MailItem)tmpOutlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            tmpMessage.HTMLBody = "Test";
            String sDisplayName = "Test";
            int iPosition = (int)tmpMessage.Body.Length + 1;
            int iAttachType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
            Outlook.Attachment oAttach = tmpMessage.Attachments.Add(@"C:\Test.txt", iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);
            tmpMessage.Subject = "Your Subject will go here.";
            Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)tmpMessage.Recipients;
            Outlook.Recipient tmpRecipient = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add("EMail");
            tmpRecipient.Resolve();
            tmpMessage.Send();
    }
```

Comment: I saw the Idea with the `HTML` as well but my Text comes from a `RichTextBox` so it's in `RTF`. Is there a good way to Convert `RTF` to `HTML`?

Comment: @E-Nuff this documentation helped me alot : https://www.codeproject.com/kb/recipes/rtfconverter.aspx

Comment: Thnk you. One last Question is it possible that the Attachment isn't displayed in the Body but insted like in a normal Mail as an extra Row?

Comment: @E-Nuff As example, when you use HTML Outlook will place the attachment in the attachment row by itself.

Comment: @E-Nuff For an example see the MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms268870.aspx